# Progressbar on Android webview

Tags: java, android, webview, progress-bar

I'm quite new to developing Android apps. Basically I'm making a webview template to display different URLs where the websites a mobile optimized.

The app has two pages:
1 splash page.
1 webview page.

I have worked through several tutorials and this part is actually working, so the problem is...

**I want to show a progress bar when the webview is loading the website which then disappears when the websites have been loaded.**

I have made a lot of tries to get this to work, but without success.

**The XML file:**
Basically have the webview with the `ID:` and a progress bar with `ID:progressbar` ( Not sure if this should be in there )

**The JAVA File:**
[Link to preeview of java file](http://dev.html24.dk/prngo_app/Javafile.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to add `ProgressBar` support.

Add the below statement before `setContentView(R.layout.layout_file)`;

```
// Adds Progrss bar Support
this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
```

Then after a call to `setContentView(R.layout.layout_file);` add this line to make progressbar visible

```
// Makes Progress bar Visible
getWindow().setFeatureInt( Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);
```

Now inside `onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)` you have to add following lines :

```
//Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded, and changes string to Loading...
MyActivity.setTitle("Loading...");
MyActivity.setProgress(progress * 100); //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded

// Return the app name after finish loading
    if(progress == 100)
         MyActivity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
```

You can refer full tutorial here : [ProgressBar in WebView](http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/08/04/adding-progress-bar-on-webview-android-tutorials/). I have referred the code from that website only.

**Edit**

Another example from official Android docs [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

Comment: Maybe I'm just stupid, but I can't really get this to work. Is it posible that you can make a working Java file? Is there something I need to change in the XML?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with this by adding a new property to your Activity:

```
protected ProgressDialog dialog;
```

When you are going to open the web add this:

```
dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "LOADING", "Website is loading...", true);
YourWebView.loadUrl(url);

/* Prevent WebView from Opening the Browser */
YourWebView.setWebViewClient(new InsideWebViewClient());
```

And then have to extend the WebViewClient class and add to the onPageFinished method:

```
protected class InsideWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
  @Override
  public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
  {
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    if(dialog != null && dialog.isShowing())
        dialog.dismiss();
  }
}
```